# Return boolean value based on string boolean input values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a paramter `params[:input]`, and its value is coming as `'true'` or `'false'` (boolean values in string).

In database, the input values are stored as `1` and `0`. I need to return boolean values based on input string values. I created a function below to return boolean values.

```
def status(input)
  return unless input.present?
  return false if ['false'].include?(input.downcase)
  return true if ['true'].include?(input.downcase)
end
```

Not sure if this is the best way. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: ``input.is_a?(String) && input.casecmp('true').zero?`` would have been far simpler. If the input is guaranteed to be a string it can be simplified even more.

Comment: @User7354632781 : Your method returns `nil` if either `input.present?` is false or if input is present, but is neither true or false (i.e. you can't distinguish on the caller side between missing input and incorrect input). Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `case`. Since there is a binary state, you probably need to decide what value is to be chosen for a fallback. E. g. when no parameter is present, you are likely still in a need to return something. I would return `false` for everything save for `'true'`:

```
def status(input)
  case input
  when 'true' then true
  when 'false' then false
  else false
  end
end
```

Or, even shorter (but less readable/idiomatic):

```
def status(input)
  'true' == input
end
```

Comment: your `case` block needed to be `end`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, without overhead of switch statements, etc, is simply this:

```
def status(input)
  input.is_a?(String) && input.casecmp?('true')
end
```

`casecmp?` ensures **case-insensitivity**, so `'true'`, `'TRUE'`, `'True'`, and any variation of different cases would all return a boolean `true`.

This could even be altered slightly more to simply ensure that input is a string by calling `to_s` on it, which will just return `self` if it is already a string.

```
def status(input)
  input.to_s.casecmp?('true')
end
```

The first is a bit safer, as depending on the object passed, `to_s` could have been overridden and supply unpredictable behavior, though highly unlikely.

Another solution is using `downcase` and comparing with `==`, but `casecmp?` is more optimized for comparison, and does not create an additional string as `downcase` would.

[Documentation for `case_cmp?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-casecmp-3F)

Comment: There's also [`casecmp?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-casecmp-3F) (with a `?`)

Comment: Indeed you are right, completely forgot about that, thanks :) Will make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to cast a string to a boolean and you are using Ruby on Rails. Why don't you use the same method that Rails itself uses to translate user input into a boolean?

```
def status(input)
  ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user(value)
end
```

The name of the method changed in different versions of Rails. The above version is for Rails 4.2. Prior Rails 4.2 use `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(value)` and since Rails 5 it is `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)`

The advantage of using the build method it that it accepts not only the strings `'true'` and `'false'` but other common input and still returns a useful boolean.